# Javascript Plotly integer slider?

Tags: javascript, plotly

Basically, I'd want to plot something like `y=x²` using Plotly, and then, I'd want a slider capable of stepping from 0 to 65535 in increment of 1 (using say keyboard Left and Right arrow for fine precision), and I'd want to display a point on the curve, corresponding to the x value input from the slider - so the point would move/"animate", as the slider is dragged.

I've only found this documentation on JavaScript Plotly sliders:

https://plotly.com/javascript/sliders/

... which shows only this kind of setup for the steps of the slider:

```js
    steps: [{
      label: 'red',
      method: 'restyle',
      args: ['line.color', 'red']
    }, {
      label: 'green',
      method: 'restyle',
      args: ['line.color', 'green']
    }, {
      label: 'blue',
      method: 'restyle',
      args: ['line.color', 'blue']
    }]
```

... that is, each step is a dict with label, method, args etc.

So, I tried something like:

```js
    var inticks = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
      inticks.push({ value: i, method: 'restyle', args: ['line.color', 'green']});
    }
...
    Plotly.newPlot( ...

          steps: inticks,
        }], // sliders
      } );
    }
```

... but this did not render any slider - and after half a minute, the browser starts complaining on "script slowing browser down". So clearly, this is not the way to go, for having an integer slider.

Is there an option to have such an integer slider in Plotly?